# How many permutations $\theta$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ have $\theta(4)=4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, permutation-cycles

How many permutations $\theta$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ have $\theta(4)=4$.

*Request vetting*

In permutations, always have bijective mappings.

After fixing one element have options available:
$=3,$ for first element, 
$=2,$ for second element, 
$=1,$ for third element.

Say, now elements left are three: $\{1,2,3\}$, the mappings possible are :
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 1  & 3\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3  & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix} $$

Want to add another question to it, for knowledge enhancement.
Find conjugate class elements of each of the six permutations above.

Request some hints, and if possible an example too. That would assist in handling bigger examples in future.

*Edit*

Based on response by @StinkingBishop, get:
Two permutations are conjugate iff they have the same lengths of cycles, regardless of which elements belong to the cycles.

There are three cycle lengths, each forms a conjugacy class with order (= number of elements in conjugacy class).

$1:  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3\end{pmatrix}$
$2: \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 1  & 3\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1  & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$
$3: \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3  & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: Do I understand it right? You are asking two questions: (1) Is it correct that the number of permutations is $6$ (which is what you have found), and (2) What are conjugate classes of those. My answer: (1) Yes.(2) Two permutations are conjugate iff they have the same lengths of cycles, regardless of which elements belong to the cycles. (You know that every permutation can be written as a product  of cycles, don't you?) Say, $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\3&2&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\2&1&3\end{pmatrix}$ are conjugate as they both have one $2$-cycle.

Comment: However, on MSE you are discouraged to post more than one question at once!

Comment: The number of permutations of $n$ elements is $n!$ and these form a group under composition of functions called $S_{n}$ . By conjugacy class do you mean in $S_{4}$ or in $S_{3}$?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I mean conjugacy class in $S_3$, as one element is fixed, so no more $S_4$ can be considered.

Comment: They correspond to the permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop will post multiple questions in future.  kindly see the edit. Have a nagging issue: due to lack of exposure to the topic, that a suitable question on this example may help. It is: what is difference between conjugacy class and cosets ?

Comment: @jiten You obtain (left) cosets by multiplying elements of a subgroup from the left by the elements of the group. In other words, if $H\le G$, you introduce the relation $g_1\sim g_2\iff(\exists h\in H)hg_1=g_2$. Similarly for the right cosets (swap $hg_1$ to $g_1h$ in the previous statement), For the conjugacy classes, introduce a relation $g_1\sim g_2\iff(\exists g\in G)g_2=g^{-1}g_1g$. Both those relations are equivalence relations and produce equivalence classes: left/right cosets of $H$ for the first relation, conjugacy classes for the second relation.

Comment: Cosets are always defined with respect to a subgroup $H\le G$, while for conjugacy classes you don't need an additional subgroup to define them.